# Ending a QSerialPort open attempt on timeout

Tags: c++, qt, timeout

I have the following code. My main concern is with function 3, sendConnectionVerification.

```
//attempts a connection with the next device in the list of available ports
void DeviceConnection::connectDevice(){
    serialPort_Controller->close();
    portsAvailable = QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts();
    qDebug() << "connecting";
    qDebug() << portsAvailable.count();
    QSerialPortInfo port;
    if (currentPosInList < portsAvailable.count()){
        portName = portsAvailable.at(currentPosInList).portName();
        setPort(portName);
        currentPosInList++;
       // serialPort_Controller->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
        sendConnectionVerification(ConnectMode::Connect);
        if (!serialPort_Controller->isOpen()){
            qDebug() << "Cannot open controller serial port";
        }
    }
    else{
        currentPosInList = 0;
    }
    emit portAttempted(alreadySetup);
}

//Configure port
void DeviceConnection::setPort(QString port){
    qDebug() << port;
    portName = port;
    serialPort_Controller->setPortName(port);     //My computer
    serialPort_Controller->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud115200);
    serialPort_Controller->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
    serialPort_Controller->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
    serialPort_Controller->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
    serialPort_Controller->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::SoftwareControl);
}


//Send connection verification. If we get more modes, overhaul the logic.
void DeviceConnection::sendConnectionVerification(int mode){
    bool open = serialPort_Controller->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
    if(open){   //Add timeout
        qDebug() << "Connected";
        serialPort_Controller->clear(QSerialPort::Output);
        //NOTE There is overlap of sending methods. Figure out how to combine them.
        if(mode == ConnectMode::Reconnect){
            addToQueue(reconnectMessage);
            //NOTE Add logic that notifies user that the reconnection has failed
        }
        else{
            qDebug() << "Sending message: " << connectMessage;
            serialPort_Controller->write(connectMessage.toUtf8());
        }
    }
    else if (!open){
        //int error = serialPort_Controller->error();
        qDebug() << "Connection error";
        if(mode == ConnectMode::Reconnect){
            removePortName(portName);
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is to open the serialPort, determine whether it returns, and make decisions based on whether the port is opened.

I am facing an issue where the code stays on the line     `bool open = serialPort_Controller->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);` for far too long, and I would like to find a way to timeout it.

For whatever reason, my `serialPort_Controller->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)` can sometimes take a long time. When testing with the Qt Creator debugger, this line is stuck on for a long time.

I have tested this code with this, which results in the timer being called only after the `serialPort_Controller->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)` is completed. My conclusion with the results is that "open" seems to be blocking. If it isn't supposed to be blocking, please let me know.

```
//attempts a connection with the next device in the list of available ports
void DeviceConnection::connectDevice(){
    serialPort_Controller->close();
    portsAvailable = QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts();
    //isValid
    qDebug() << "connecting";
    qDebug() << portsAvailable.count();
    QSerialPortInfo port;
    if (currentPosInList < portsAvailable.count()){
        portName = portsAvailable.at(currentPosInList).portName();
        qDebug() << "Port status " << portsAvailable.at(currentPosInList).isNull();
        setPort(portName);
        currentPosInList++;
        sendConnectionVerification(ConnectMode::Connect);
        if (!serialPort_Controller->isOpen()){
            qDebug() << "Cannot open controller serial port";
        }
    }
    else{
        currentPosInList = 0;
    }
    emit portAttempted(alreadySetup);
}

//Configure port
void DeviceConnection::setPort(QString port){
    qDebug() << port;
    portName = port;
    serialPort_Controller->setPortName(port);     //My computer
    serialPort_Controller->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud115200);
    serialPort_Controller->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
    serialPort_Controller->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
    serialPort_Controller->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
    serialPort_Controller->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::SoftwareControl);
}

//Send connection verification. If we get more modes, overhaul the logic.
void DeviceConnection::sendConnectionVerification(int mode){
    //Build timeout for serialPort_Controller->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite). Still doesn't work.
    qDebug() << "timer";
    QTimer *timeout = new QTimer;   //NOTE This thing has a bit of unexpected behavior since it has no parent
    timeout->setSingleShot(true);
    connect(timeout, &QTimer::timeout, this, &DeviceConnection::closeConnection);
    connect(timeoutThread, SIGNAL(started()), timeout, SLOT(start()));
    connect(timeoutThread, SIGNAL(finished()), timeout, SLOT(stop()));
    timeout->moveToThread(timeoutThread);
    timeout->setInterval(500);
    timeoutThread->start();

    qDebug() << serialPort_Controller->isOpen();
    if(serialPort_Controller->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)){   //Add timeout
        //qDebug() << serialPort_Controller->isOpen();
        qDebug() << "Connected";
        timeoutThread->exit();
        serialPort_Controller->clear(QSerialPort::Output);
        //NOTE There is overlap of sending methods. Figure out how to combine them.
        if(mode == ConnectMode::Reconnect){
            addToQueue(reconnectMessage);
            //NOTE Add logic that notifies user that the reconnection has failed
        }
        else{
            qDebug() << "Sending message: " << connectMessage;
            serialPort_Controller->write(connectMessage.toUtf8());
        }
    }
    else if(!serialPort_Controller->waitForReadyRead(2000)){
        //int error = serialPort_Controller->error();
        qDebug() << "Connection error";
        if(mode == ConnectMode::Reconnect){
            removePortName(portName);
        }
    }
    disconnect(timeoutThread, SIGNAL(started()), timeout, SLOT(start()));
    disconnect(timeoutThread, SIGNAL(finished()), timeout, SLOT(stop()));
}

//closes connection to device
void DeviceConnection::closeConnection(){
    qDebug() << "close connection";
    serialPort_Controller->close();
    //portList.clear();
}
```

The output:

```
Port status  false
"COM10"
DateTime before open  QDateTime(2023-07-17 09:31:28.242 GMT Daylight Time Qt::LocalTime)
false
Connection error
DateTime after open  QDateTime(2023-07-17 09:31:35.455 GMT Daylight Time Qt::LocalTime)
Cannot open controller serial port
close connection
```

An example of a successful open:

```
Port status  false
"COM9"
DateTime before open  QDateTime(2023-07-17 10:03:31.243 GMT Daylight Time Qt::LocalTime)
false
Connected
Sending message:  "TOARM_VALCN_00000000_4C\r\n"
DateTime after open  QDateTime(2023-07-17 10:03:31.244 GMT Daylight Time Qt::LocalTime)
```

My first attempt at a timeout solution was this:

```
//Send connection verification. If we get more modes, overhaul the logic.
void DeviceConnection::sendConnectionVerification(int mode){
    if(serialPort_Controller->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite) || serialPort_Controller->waitForReadyRead(2000)){   //Add timeout
        qDebug() << "Connected";
        serialPort_Controller->clear(QSerialPort::Output);
        //NOTE There is overlap of sending methods. Figure out how to combine them.
        if(mode == ConnectMode::Reconnect){
            addToQueue(reconnectMessage);
            //NOTE Add logic that notifies user that the reconnection has failed
        }
        else{
            qDebug() << "Sending message: " << connectMessage;
            serialPort_Controller->write(connectMessage.toUtf8());
        }
    }
    else{
        //int error = serialPort_Controller->error();
        qDebug() << "Connection error";
        if(mode == ConnectMode::Reconnect){
            removePortName(portName);
        }
    }
}
```

This didn't work, which I'm guessing is because that waitForReadyRead doesn't have anything to do with opening the port, but has something to do with data being ready. My second attempt was this:

```
//Send connection verification. If we get more modes, overhaul the logic.
void DeviceConnection::sendConnectionVerification(int mode){
    QTimer *timeout = new QTimer(this);
    QTimer::singleShot(1000, this, &DeviceConnection::closeConnection);
    bool open = serialPort_Controller->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
    if(open){   //Add timeout
        qDebug() << "Connected";
        serialPort_Controller->clear(QSerialPort::Output);
        //NOTE There is overlap of sending methods. Figure out how to combine them.
        if(mode == ConnectMode::Reconnect){
            addToQueue(reconnectMessage);
            //NOTE Add logic that notifies user that the reconnection has failed
        }
        else{
            qDebug() << "Sending message: " << connectMessage;
            serialPort_Controller->write(connectMessage.toUtf8());
        }
    }
    else if (!open){
        //int error = serialPort_Controller->error();
        qDebug() << "Connection error";
        if(mode == ConnectMode::Reconnect){
            removePortName(portName);
        }
    }
}

//closes connection to device
void DeviceConnection::closeConnection(){
    serialPort_Controller->close();
}
```

This didn't work either, because closeConnection is only seemingly reached when  `serialPort_Controller->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)` is completed.

Please let me know if more information is required. This is Qt 5.15.2 on Windows 10. This is for a desktop application, so also Win10.